# Why do I need reset File Encodings when I restore my project from a zip backup file in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I have set File Encodings as UTF-8 in both office PC and Home PC for my projec E:\Android_Studio_Project\MyTest, and I backup the whole folder E:\Android_Studio_Project\MyTest to aa.zip as the project backup at office PC.
After I restore the latest aa.zip at my home PC, I find the File Encodings is reset default value GBK, I have to reset File Encodings for the project, why?

BTW, eclipse store all settings in .metadata folder, if I copy the .metadata folder to different PC, the all PC's eclipse have the same UI and settings. I don't know if Android Studio have a folder just like .metadata.

Note Import Settings file settings.jar can't do that.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting UTF-8 in all three places:

1. IDE Encoding (first combobox on your screenshot)
2. Project Encoding (second combobox on your screenshot)
3. Gradle build files

   `android {
       ...
       compileOptions {
           encoding "UTF-8"
           sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
           targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
       }
   }`

Comment: Thanks! would you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634265/how-to-set-cannot-resolve-symbol-font-color-in-android-studio ?