# How to set "cannot resolve symbol" font color in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

Now I use Android studio instead of eclipse, I hope to set the font color of "cannot resolve symbol"  in editor, but there are many choices in Settings UI, I don't know where I can find the choice, could you help me? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Android Studio myself. However, judging by red "UnknownType" in colors preview, the color you seek is not "unresolved symbol", but instead generic error. Look for "Error" or something like that on the list. You can also try to click "UnknownType" in colors preview, maybe Android Studio is smart enough to select the color from the list for you.